# how to capture values in form with too many fields (48)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a form that needs to have 48 check boxes for coordinates; its like a matrix of 6*8 checkboxes.

Then I have to submit these coordinates in a string "coordinates_field" in the database.

The `coordinates_field` will have an array of coordinates like:

```
coordinates_field = [4-7,1-3,5-9] #48 coordinates
```

Should I create 48 `attr_accessors` and 48 checkboxes in the form, or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I recently had a similar situation while reproducing a government form.  I ended up with 43 checkboxes and 28 radio buttons.  It's actually not so bad.  I was able to supply the data embedded as a Javascript array on the page, and handled building the form in Javascript.  The page was far smaller and the Javascript/jQuery code was easier to deal with than the corresponding HTML would have been.  I saved the objects as JSON in a single database field; I didn't need to search on the values, so all I had to do was convert to/from JSON when I needed the button values.